# watch in AlpineJS is not reflecting oldValue

Tags: alpine.js

Im trying to detect a change in a variable in store global.
But according to this - https://alpinejs.dev/magics/watch - I should be getting oldValue. But (value, oldValue) are same.

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () =>
{
    Alpine.store('global_data',
    {
        products:
        [
            {
                name: 'batmobile',
                price_USD: 20,
                price_INR: 1660, // 20 x 83
            },
            {
                name: 'herbie',
                price_USD: 35,
                price_INR: 2905, // 35 x 83
            },
            {
                name: 'delorean',
                price_USD: 51,
                price_INR: 4233, // 51 x 83
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

```html
<div
    x-data=""
    x-init="
    $watch('$store.global_data.products', (value, oldValue) =>
    {
        console.log('oldValue = ', oldValue);
        console.log('value = ', value);
    })
    "
>
    <template x-for="(product, index) in $store.global_data.products">
        <div>
            <span x-text="product.name"></span> : 
            <input x-model="product.price_USD" /> USD
            =
            <input x-model="product.price_INR" /> INR
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.12.3/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/discussions/3467?sort=top)

Comment: As explained in Pippo's link, you get the old object which happens to be the same object as the new. It's because it's not a new instance, but rather the same instance, by reference. I suppose it's an undersight from Alpine. You're better off following the value manually in this case, and ensure you clone the object. You can read more about cloning [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: How do I follow the value in here using `$watch` ?